# Early exit from function in a forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

How can I early exit from a function in my TypeScript file?

```
checkIfFollowed(){
    
    this.currentUserInfos.followed.forEach(element => {
        if(18785 == 18785){
            console.log('its true');                
            this.alreadyFollowed = true;
            return; // Exit checkIfFollowed() here
        }

    });

    this.alreadyFollowed = false;
    console.log('the end');
    return;
}
```

When I'm running it, it's executed completely, but it should exit after the first:

> 'its true'

But in my console, I get:

> its true
>
> its true
>
> the end

Foreach loops 2 times as expected, but why the method doesn't stop after hitting a "return"?

I'm not trying to get out of the forEach, but ending the method 'checkIfFollowed' in the foreach.

'the end' should not be printed.

Comment: Will you please post currentUserInfos;

Comment: There's 2 objects in currentUserInfos.followed
It's just a nested object, nothing special

Comment: Use Array#some from here :https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: What is the actual requrement? You are hard coding the if check here as `if(18785 == 18785)`. I dont think this is your actual requirement.

Comment: I'd like to know how to end a method anywhere.

Comment: @echonax, thanks for your answer, but it's not. i'm trying to exit checkIfFollowed method, not only the forEach.

Comment: You can use `for` instead of `.foreach`.

Comment: @Toodoo the reason you can't exit `checkIfFollowed` is that you can't exit `forEach`

Comment: Yup, didn't get it, but thanks to @gsc i got it now ! Thanks for your help echnoax !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach, with `for` loop:

```typescript
checkIfFollowed() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.currentUserInfos.followed.length; ++ i) {
    if (18785 == 18785) {
      console.log('its true');                
      this.alreadyFollowed = true;
      return; // exit checkIfFollowed() here
    }
  }

  this.alreadyFollowed = false;
  console.log('the end');
  return;
}
```

Comment: It works. Weird, why it doesn't work with forEach approach ? Many thanks.

Comment: Because using `forEach`, you are entering a new function (`.foreach(function (e) {…})`) and calling `return` there stops that new function and not the parent (`checkIfFollowed`) one. You are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead of forEach

.every() (stops looping the first time the iterator returns false or something falsey)

With every():

```
checkIfFollowed(){

        this.currentUserInfos.followed.every(function(element, index) {
            // Do something.
            if (18785 == 18785){
                console.log('its true');                
                this.alreadyFollowed = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(this.alreadyFollowed) 
        {
            return ;
        }
        this.alreadyFollowed = false;
        console.log('the end');
        return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try this, the 'return' breaks the loop, but doesn't end the method.

Comment: It returns same output?

Comment: Try now , forgot to return false;

Comment: Here iteration of method will not stop. But you can restrict the execution of some line of code by `if` check. But I think it is better to use `some` rather `forEach`

Comment: .every() (stops looping the first time the iterator returns false or something falsey)

Comment: .some() (stops looping the first time the iterator returns true or something truthy)

Comment: Thanks @ParthaSarathiGhosh , updated my answer with both.

Comment: @Toodoo , Will you please check now ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi it's end the loop but not the function :/

Comment: Will you please explain , what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Its there now, please have a look @Toodoo

Comment: It seems we can't do it with forEach or every. @gsc got the answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You could also not fight `foreach` :) and do it this way:

```
checkIfFollowed(){

    const filtered = this.currentUserInfos.followed
       .filter(el => el.id === 18785) // or some other condition
       .forEach(element => {
         // maybe you don't need to do anything here
         // or you can continue processing the element and you know you only have 
         // items that you want
      });

   this.alreadyFollowed = filtered.length > 0;
   console.log('the end');
//    return; // no need for an empty return at the end of a function.
}
```

HTH